# Knockout computed vs custom binding calculation order

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I defined a custom binding that alters some way an observable's property, let's say customProperty. (for example):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //computes some value depending on observable value
        //...
        valueAccessor().customProperty = someValue;
    }
};
```

I also have a computed observable that triggers on  my customBinded observable, in which I need the value of customProperty updated.
It turns out logging inside custom binding and in computed code that computed is calculated before customBinding, so it reads old customProperty value.

Can I specify that binding has priority over computeds, or is there some workaround to achieve computed to "wait" for custom binding?

Comment: can you make the customProperty also an observable? My guess is that it should fire the computed observable again..

Comment: Not so feasible to turn customProperty into an observable, but it could be an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Rate-limiting observable notifications](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) to delay the execution of the computed observable. e.g.

```
viewModel.computed = ko.computed(function() {
  var input = viewModel.input();
  return viewModel.input.customProperty + ' ' + input;
}).extend({rateLimit: 10 });
```

The slight delay will allow the binding to execute before the computed observable.  See this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/r09yo532/) for a demonstration.